# click listener only fires once with a render method inside it

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a click listener on a button that resets the innerhtml of a div with a render method.  taking out the render the click listener fires every time i click, with the render  in there it doesn't.

i've tried removing the html tagging and all external function calls, still same problem

why does that render prevent the firing or why would anything prevent it from firing (more than once)?

setup: bundling js from deno

```
const myTemplate = (formData: HCPConfig) => {
  return html` ... `;}

//byId just returns an el or throws an error
const rootEl = byId("form"); 
function render(el: Element, content: string) {
  el.innerHTML = content;
 
}
render(rootEl, myTemplate(formData)); //this renders fine on page load
const action = byId("submitty");

action.addEventListener("click", function (e: Event) {
  console.log(e);
  //this prevents the event listener from firing more than once
  render(rootEl, myTemplate(formData)); 
 
});
```

Comment: So `console.log(e)` is logging only once, when you have render inside? Are you rerendering the DOM with render?

Comment: Is your `#submitty` button placed inside the `#form` element?

Comment: yes, the log only fires once unless i comment out render then works every time i click the button.  submitty is not in a form element.  i took that out wondering if that was the problem @TusharShahi

Comment: the form question did get thinking... the button was inside the template i was rendering.  i moved it out and put it on the html page directly and now it works...  the rerendering of the button must have been resetting the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by putting the button that has the clicklistener attached to it outside of the the item getting re-rendered.

```
const ssFormCtl = (content = "Submit"): string => {
  return html`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitty">
    ${content}
  </button>`;
};
const myTemplate = (formData: HCPConfig) => {
  return html` ... `;}

//byId just returns an el or throws an error
const rootEl = byId("form"); 
const ctlEl = byId("ssFormCtl");
function render(el: Element, content: string) {
  el.innerHTML = content;
 
}
render(rootEl, myTemplate(formData)); 
render(ctlEl, ssFormCtl());
const action = byId("submitty");

action.addEventListener("click", function (e: Event) {
  console.log(e);
  render(rootEl, myTemplate(formData)); 
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `#submitty` button is inside the `#form` element, you are overwriting the button and all the other contents of `#form` with the content. You should only overwrite a part of the form by making a div or other element inside the form.

Comment: OP has mentioned that the button is not inside the form.

Comment: `#submitty` is not inside a form element

Comment: @shivam, see my comment above.  your point was valid, it just had nothing to do with the form.